# How would one use Bézout's theorem to prove that if $d = \gcd(a,b)\ \text{then} \ \gcd(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Note: I have checked the questions with the same title and I am after something more specific.

I am doing my first course in discrete mathematics, and came across the following proposition that I was asked to prove:

Let $a,b,d \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $d = \gcd(a,b)\ \text{then} \ \gcd\Bigl(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}\Bigr) = 1$.

My first thought was to prove it by contradiction, and I did it as follows,

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and suppose that $d = \gcd(a,b).$

Assume that  $\ \gcd\Bigl(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}\Bigr) = c$, where $c \neq 1 $.

Then $c\mid\frac{a}{d} \ \text{and} \   c\mid\frac{b}{d}$, that is, $a = cmd \ \text{and} \ b = cnd$ , where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

This implies that there is a integer $cd$ that divides both $a$ and $b$, where $cd > d$. But, $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, which yields a contradiction. Therefore, the assumption is false, and  $\ \gcd\Bigl(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}\Bigr) = 1$.

This is my approach, but the solution presented by the TA's notes uses a different approach which, given the way it was presented, I could not understand how it would prove the proposition. The approach uses Bézout's theorem, which was presented to us in following manner:

Consider the equation $$ax+by=c,$$ where $a,b,c$ are integers, with $a$ and $b$ not both zero. if $ c=d$, where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ then the equation has a solution in integers $x,y$.

if $d\mid c$ then the equation has a solution in integers.

if $d\nmid c$ then the equation has no solution in integers.

The proof presented went on to apply this theorem to prove the proposition:

Consider the equation$$ax+by=d,$$ where $d = \gcd(a,b)$ (with integer coefficients).

Dividing both sides by $d$ yields,

$$\frac{a}{d}x+\dfrac{b}{d}y=1,$$ where $\dfrac{a}{d}$ and $\dfrac{b}{d}$ are both integers (follows from definition of that $\gcd$)

and then it goes on to say by Bézout's theorem, we can conclude that $\ \gcd\Bigl(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}\Bigr) = 1$

Now, I am really confused as to what role Bézout's theorem (the way it is presented to us) has played in their conclusion; the theorem does not say that if there are integer solutions then the RHS must be the gcd of the coefficients. $\textbf{And}$ if they claimed that $\dfrac{a}{d}$ and $\dfrac{b}{d}$ are relatively prime, wouldn't that mean that, by definition, their greatest common divisor must be 1? Because if so, then I really do not see the need to use the theorem in the first place.

Given that some of the proofs for this proposition (that I have seen) here and on other websites use Bézout's theorem, I am inclined to believe that there is something wrong with my way of thinking, as in there is something I am not seeing, so I would appreciate it if you could clarify this for me. I have attached my proof just to see if it is correct in case the proof presented in my notes turned out to be incomplete or incorrect.

edit: small corrections

Comment: Good question, w.r.t being a first timer on the site. +1

Comment: My attempt that I presented in my question uses a proof by contradiction, which, as you suggested, seems to be an easy way to prove the statement. My problem is with using Bezout's theorem, and more precisely with the way it was used as described in my question. @Peter

Comment: I just noticed that, so I deleted my comment.

Comment: @Bernard, I added a missing '\' to one part of the syntax and your profile logo disappeared from the question's main page, as in it no longer shows that you have edited my post. I wanted to let you know because I do not want you to lose the credit after all the editing that you have done to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Bézout's theorem twice. First, if $\gcd(a,b)=d$, Bézout's theorem says that the equation $ax+by=d$ has integer solutions, since $d\mid d$.

Now fix the values $x=x_1,y=y_1$ that solve it. They also solve the equation $\frac adx+\frac bd y=1$. If $\gcd(\frac ad,\frac bd)\not\mid 1$, Bézout's theorem would say that this equation has no solutions. But we know it does have a solution, so $\gcd(\frac ad,\frac bd)\mid 1$, which implies it is equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely missed that, an oversight on my part.  Would my attempt be considered a sufficient proof?

Comment: @Zzzz1111 Definitely, in fact what you did is how I would normally prove it.

Answer (score 3):

By Bézout's theorem, we can write $ax+by=d$ with $x,y\in \mathbb Z$ and so
$\frac ad x+\frac bd y=1$.

Therefore,
every common divisor of $\frac ad$  and $\frac bd$ divides the LHS and so divides the RHS, and so must divide $1$.

Thus $\gcd(\frac ad,\frac bd)=1$.