# Let d=gcd(a,b). Prove that gcd(a/d, b/d)=1 (using Bezout's identity)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I was hoping someone could help look at my attempt at this proof and how I might finish it.

By Bezout's identity, can rewrite our given information as... $\gcd(a,b)=d \Longrightarrow ax+by=d$

Dividing this equation by $d$, we get $\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}y=1$

Bezout's Identity states that if $\frac{a}{d}, \frac{b}{d} \in \mathbb Z^+$, then there exists $x,y$ such that $\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}y=\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$.

Since we have already concluded that $\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}y=1$, $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$.

Is this a complete proof? I think I have to show that $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ are in fact integers, but not sure how I do that.

Thank you!!

Comment: well, $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, right? So in particular it is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, i.e., it divides both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The point is that the gcd is the *smallest* positive integer that can be written in the form $ax+by$. This is very important. You should stop to understand/explain why $a/d$ and $b/d$ are integers, yes.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does/should the fact that the gcd is the smallest positive integer that satisfies the equation come up in this proof? I understand that but am not sure I see where that comes into the proof.

Comment: If I write $4=1\cdot 6 + (-1)\cdot 2$, does that mean $4=\gcd(2,6)$? Reread the whole Bezout identity discussion carefully!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would one use Bézout's theorem to prove that if $d = \gcd(a,b)\ \text{then} \ \gcd(\dfrac{a}{d}, \dfrac{b}{d}) = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731432/how-would-one-use-b%c3%a9zouts-theorem-to-prove-that-if-d-gcda-b-textthen)